# MySQL хранение двоичных чисел

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Есть числа типа: 
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 (168 символов).

Эти числа являются набором конфигурации по **168 пунктам**, в виде `TRUE(1)` и `FALSE(0)`.

Как лучше его хранить чтобы и места не занимало и быстро считать записать в бд.?

В каком типе полей лучше хранить их?

**UPD:**
Корректирую задачу: набор из 168 цифр - это почасовые настройки на каждый день. Т.е., 7х24=168. Требуется, в связке PHP+MySQL побитово этот конфиг записать в таблицу list->(поле)settings.

```
<?php
$d1='111111111111111111000000';  
$d2='111111000000111111111111';  
$d3='111111111111111111111111';  
$d4='111001111111111100111111';  
$d5='111111111111111111111111';  
$d6='110111111110111111111111';  
$d7='000000011111111111111111';  
$settings=$d1.$d2.$d3.$d4.$d5.$d6.$d7;

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","db_user","db_password","db");
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO list (settings) 
VALUES ($settings)");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Сейчас структура бд такая:

```
`settings` tinyblob NOT NULL,
```

Занимает это дело соответсвенно [BLOB - 168 Байт]
Хотелось бы уместить в 168 бит(+-), т.к. будет много таких конфигов.
Как это реализовать это на PHP?

Comment: А как много (для каждой записи) у Вас обычно заполнено значений из этих 168 возможных?

Comment: Ну так и клади бинарные данные в свой blob. Зачем пихать строки?

Comment: @Qwertiy как!? напиши пример пожалуйста. Что дописать в коде?

Comment: А чем вам поле BIT не подходит?
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/bit-field-literals.html

Answer (score 6):

Если это действительно набор настроек - то лучше хранить его в отдельной таблице, в формате "имя - флаг on/off".

Полный набор настроек точно так же вычитывается одним запросом, а работать с ним будет легче в разы. Особенно если в какой-то момент вам придется настройку #40 удалить.

---

Для обновленной версии вопроса - если это почасовые настройки - их стоит хранить в таблице вида

```
Номер конфига | День недели | Час | On/Off
```

И вам не придется работать с битами вообще. Можно спокойно загрузить весь конфиг, и в одно обращение узнать настройку для нужного часа нужного дня.

Если волнуетесь за занимаемый объем - напрасно. Это около килобайта на один конфиг. Примерно 0.00000004$ при современных ценах на storage.

Comment: Это как? Создать 168 полей с TinyINT?

Comment: @TommiVersetti создать одно поле. и добавить в таблицу 168 записей. по одной для каждой настройки.

Comment: Хотелось бы с битами напрямую работать... как реализовать?

Comment: @TommiVersetti удобно - никак

Comment: Вы когда хотите помочь, пишите внятней, чтобы понятно было не только вам. Я новичек, мне нужно:    `Пояснить | Разжевать | Показать`   Спасибо.

Comment: @Tommi совсем разжевать не могу, могу только посоветовать - не усложняйте код. Работа с битам - этот значительное усложнение, постарайтесь обойтись без неё :)

Answer (score 3):

если нужно визуально читать тогда храните в **HEX** коде (`char(42)`)

если чисто бинарный тогда и `blob` можно и `char(21)`

**UPD:**
если нужно использовать конкретный бит советую использовать `BIGINT`

для 168 бит можно сделать 2 поле с `BIGINT` значениями (bigint = 8 byte = 64 bit)

в MySQL есть готовые функции работы с битовыми операциями

1. **BIT_COUNT()* - возврашает количество 1 в bigint
2. **&**    логическое AND
3. **~**    обратное значения
4. **|**    логическое OR
5. **^**    логическое XOR
6. **<<**   здвиг в лево
7. **>>**   здвиг на право

если нужен конкретный быть можно сделать так

значения в базе 29 (... 0001 1101) а нам нужно последные 4 значения (1111 = 15)

```
 SELECT 29 & 15;     
   -> 13
```

как видите 13 (1101) значит 2е значение не совпадает

думаю так лучше

**UPD:**

увидел Update вопроса и пришлось обновить ответ

если у вас уже имеется *7 дней по 24 часа* тогда советую не оптимизировать через blob а использовать 7 переменный на каждый день. так даже легче по дням искать.

```
<?php
$d1=bindec('111111111111111111000000');  
$d2=bindec('111111000000111111111111');  
$d3=bindec('111111111111111111111111');  
$d4=bindec('111001111111111100111111');  
$d5=bindec('111111111111111111111111');  
$d6=bindec('110111111110111111111111');  
$d7=bindec('000000011111111111111111');  


$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","db_user","db_password","db");
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO list (d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7) 
VALUES ($d1,$d2,$d3,$d4,$d5,$d6,$d7)");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

где структура базы будет `MEDIUMINT` который имеет размер `24 bit`

почему выбрал эту структуру.

Если нужно проверить, Вторник с 12:00 по 15:00 делаем так

```
$day = 2;
$d = bindec('00000000000111100000000');
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","db_user","db_password","db");
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT d$day & $d FROM list WHERE d$day & $d > 0");

mysqli_close($con);
```

если есть результат, значит в эти время по настройкам есть хотя бы ОДИН `1`

а конкретно какие места `1` можно проверить из ответа запроса

Comment: Это число является набором конфигурации по 168 пунктам, в виде TRUE(1) FALSE(0). Так вот как лучше его хранить чтобы и места не занимало и быстро считать записать в бд.?

Comment: 64x2=128... остаток 40 - неудобный замут с 3мя полями

Comment: @TommiVersetti да 3 поля. но решать вам. кому как удобно. `SELECT * FROM table where  field1 & 15 = 15` дает все фильтрованные данные

Answer (score 3):

Эм.. Хочется сохранить как 168 битовых колонок...
Но как-то многовато. Возможно, стоит пересмотреть структуру базы?

> @Qwertiy как!? напиши пример пожалуйста. Что дописать в коде?

Если нужно иметь blob, то записывай не строку, а массив байт.
Конкретно для примера в вопросе этот массив такой:

```
255, 255, 192, 252, 15, 255, 255, 255, 255, 231, 255, 63, 255, 255, 255, 223, 239, 255, 1, 255, 255
```

Получил его так:

```
`$d1='111111111111111111000000';  
$d2='111111000000111111111111';  
$d3='111111111111111111111111';  
$d4='111001111111111100111111';  
$d5='111111111111111111111111';  
$d6='110111111110111111111111';  
$d7='000000011111111111111111';`
.match(/[01](?=[01'])/g).join("").match(/.{8}/g).map(function(s) { return parseInt(s, 2) })
```

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению.

Comment: @norbornen, обоснуй, почему ответ "сделай 168 битовых колонок" ответом не является.

Comment: не содержит никаких рекомендаций или конкретных предложений, которые позволили бы топикстартеру продвинуться в решении. Скорее комментарий, чем ответ. Имхо.

Comment: @Qwertiy поясни пожалуйста примером, то что хочешь донести. Мне кажется ты копаешь в правильную сторону.

Comment: @TommiVersetti, если есть набор флагов, то логично их так и хранить в виде флагов (по одному в колонке), но то, что их 168, наталкивает на мысль, что ты делаешь что-то не то. Поясни, зачем тебе их столько и как их планируется использовать.

Comment: обновил задачу выше...может яснее станет?

Comment: @Tommi, ответ обновлён.

Comment: Спасибо! Всего ответа я конечно не получил т.к. не PHP, но направление понял. Т.е. мне нужно перевести мою строку в бинарный вид. Будем учиться

Answer (score 3):

А не приходило в голову использовать стандартный функционал? На физическом уровне хранятся именно биты.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html

пример запроса к значению одного
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE FIND_IN_SET('value',set_col)>0;

Как вижу это я - каждый бит именуется отдельно, FIND_IN_SET позволяет получить по указанному "биту" значение - есть или нет.

Ограничения - одним столбцом хранить не больше 64 значений, 255 на таблицу суммарно по столбцам. Вроде влезает.

Answer (score 2):

У меня реализована подобная схема. Только полный конфигурационный набор = 105 знаков... но суть остается та же.

Таблица с такой структурой

```
CREATE TABLE `web_settings` (
  ...
  `settings1` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `settings2` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  ...
)
```

(подразумевается, что, если увеличится кол-во настроек, просто добавляется `settings3`...)

Весь конфигурационный набор режется на куски по 60 знаков (`array_chunk()`) и загоняется в MySQL с переводом в десятиричную систему:

```
UPDATE web_settings SET settings1=CONV(BINARY(".$chunk[0]."), 2, 10), settings2=CONV(BINARY(".$chunk[1]."), 2, 10)
```

А чтобы достать данные из базы переводим обратно в двоичную

```
SELECT BIN(settings1) as set1, BIN(settings2) as set2 FROM web_settings
```

В PHP объединяем в один набор и загоняем в массив `array_split` и все.

Насчет занимаемого места: `bigint` съедает 8 байт (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html), т.е. у нас - 16... При наших объемах это приемлемо.

Почему конфигурационный набор режется именно на 60 знаков? Ну как... В идеале было бы порезать по 64, но в этом случае полученное десятиричное число не влезет в bigint. Пришлось уменьшать - уменьшили до ближайшей круглой цифры.

Из проблем, что мы столкнулись, могу назвать лишь то, что если есть какой-то конфигурационный параметр, у которого не два состояния, а три (yes/no/n.a.), то приходится хранить отдельно..

Хочу также оговориться, что система была реализована несколько лет назад. Может она и не идеальна, но тогда ru.so не было, чтобы спросить :):):):):)

Answer (score 2):

Если идти простым путем, то надо просто завести 7 полей типа BIT(24) в базе данных. Можно конечно завести 2 поля BIT(64) и одно BIT(40), но это уже вам решать.
Именно благодаря такому типу полей (столбцов) БД запрос на добавление данных прост весьма

```
<?php
$d1="b'111111111111111111000000'";  // специальный синтаксис b'...'
$d2="b'111111000000111111111111'";  
$d3="b'111111111111111111111111'";  
$d4="b'111001111111111100111111'";  
$d5="b'111111111111111111111111'";  
$d6="b'110111111110111111111111'";  
$d7="b'000000011111111111111111'";  

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","db_user","db_password","db");
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO list (settings1,settings2,settings3,settings4,settings5,settings6,settings7) 
VALUES ($d1,$d2,$d3,$d4,$d5,$d6,$d7)");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Можно не пользоваться вариантом `b'...'`, а писать прямо числа в базу (преобразовав строки в числа функцией `bindec()`). 
При считывании данных из базы, вы будете получать целое число и его надо преобразовать функцией php `decbin()` в двоичную строку.
Это по моему самое очевидное и простое решение, потому что тут не надо использовать тип MEDIUMINT и прочие костыли.